# Facebook author name doesn't display

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am trying to add author name for my [blog ham học](http://www.hamhoc.net/) look like 
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJMCr.png)
 and here is my code

```
<meta property='og:locale' content='vi_VN' />
<meta property='og:url' expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' />
<meta property='og:type' content="article" /> 
<meta property='article:publisher' content='my_personal_account_url' />
<meta property='article:author' content='my_fanpage_url' />
<meta property='og:rich_attachment' content='true' />
<meta property='article:section' content='Download' />
```

But it doesn't work for me, i've tried to use debugger tool but still doesn't display. I read some post about this issue and i tried to use my fanpage id,... but nothing changes. My friend's blog still display it. Can someone help me please.

Comment: You need to use IDs, not URLs. Did you refresh the FB cache after you made changes?

Comment: yes, i tried both url and id then refresh fb cache but didn't work. i see some website uses url